# How to get android bluetooth SPP uuid

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, spp

I'm trying to write an app to communicate between different bluetooth devices, following the official API Guides.

I tried to make my device (installed the app, nexus s, v4.1.2) as a client connect to a remote device (nexus 7, v4.4.2) as a server, but got almost 10 uuids of the server device when I called `fetchUuidsWithSdp()` and `getUuids()`. By the way, there is no `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`, which is mentioned in the android reference.

How do I find out which uuid is the right one for SPP communication?